# java dom parser getgetAttribute for integer attribute

Tags: java, dom, getattribute

I have an XML element that looks something like `<student id=1> .... </student>` .
When I try to use the getAttribute API provided by the dom parser [1], I get the following error:
Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "id".

If I add quotes tothe xml to make it look like: `<student id="1"> .... </student>`
Then the error goes away.

I don't want to change all my xmls (thousands of the them). Is there any code fix that I can do?

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

> I have an XML element that looks something like `<student id=1> .... </student>`

Well, no, you don't have an XML element looking like that.  It's simply not XML.

The quotes around attribute values are a required part of the syntax, and no xml parser will be able to parse your "xml" without them.

You should change your xml to make it valid.  If that xml is being produced by a program, it will be best to change that program so that it produces valid xml.